# How to efficiently convert Keras model to pytorch model in multiagent RL using nn.Modulelist or otherwise?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Does anybody know an efficient way of defining a Keras model given below to the PyTorch model?

I am trying to train an Actor critic network in Keras and Pytorch for a transportation application. I am calling the Actor Pnet or class ActorNetwork to select actions at each time step t belongs to [0,T], where T is an episode length. I am training for 2-3 million episodes, thus speed is important to me. Also, after each episode, I am storing the buffer and doing the training of both actor and critic networks.

For Keras Model I am using:
TF 1.5.0, Keras 2.1.6, on Xenon CPUs:
Average training time for 100 episodes = ~5 sec

For pytorch model:
Pytorch 1.7.1, on GPU: Quadro RTX 8000
Average training time for 100 episodes = ~14 sec

```
#Bunch of inputs

inp_IRI = Input(shape=(ncomp_pav, nstcomp_IRI))

inp_CCI = Input(shape=(ncomp_pav, nstcomp_CCI))

inp_deck = Input(shape=(ncomp_deck, nstcomp_deck))
inp_extr_st = Input(shape=(ncomp_pav,))
inp_age = Input(shape=(tot_comp,))
inp_yt = Input(shape=(1,))
inp_t = Input(shape=(1,))
x_IRI = Flatten()(inp_IRI)
x_CCI = Flatten()(inp_CCI)
x_deck = Flatten()(inp_deck)
x_p = concatenate(inputs = [x_IRI,x_CCI,x_deck, inp_extr_st, inp_age,inp_yt, inp_t])

#Actor Network defined for each component
for i in range(tot_comp):
    vars()['x_p%d'%i]= Dense(200, activation='relu')(x_p)
    vars()['x_p%d'%i]= Dense(200, activation='relu')(vars()['x_p%d'%i])
    vars()['out_p%d'%i] = Dense(nacomp,activation = 'softmax')(vars()['x_p%d'%i])
out = list(np.zeros(tot_comp))
for i in range(tot_comp):
    out[i] = vars()['out_p%d'%i]
sgdp = Adam(lr=0.0001)
Pnet = Model(inputs=[inp_IRI,inp_CCI,inp_deck, inp_extr_st,inp_age, inp_yt ,inp_t], outputs=out)
```

I have tried something like the following, it worked but it slowed down the code (in training time) like 2-3 times, and performance (means the value function V) also went down in comparison to the Keras model, is there a better way to code decentralized agents in Pytorch?

```
class ActorNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,tot_comp,actor_lr,input_dims,n_action = 10,fc1_dims = 200,fc2_dims = 200):#,name,chkpt_dir='tmp/actorCritic'):
        
        super(ActorNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.fc1_dims = fc1_dims
        self.fc2_dims = fc2_dims
        self.n_action = n_action
        self.tot_comp = tot_comp
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(self.input_dims, self.fc1_dims)
        self.Agentlayers1 = nn.ModuleList([self.layer1 for _ in range(self.tot_comp)])
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(self.fc1_dims, self.fc2_dims)
        self.Agentlayers2 = nn.ModuleList([self.layer2 for _ in range(self.tot_comp)])
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(self.fc2_dims, self.n_action)
        self.outputLayer = nn.ModuleList([self.layer3 for _ in range(self.tot_comp)])

    def forward (self,state): # here state must be concatenated input features
        x_agent = []
        for i in range(self.tot_comp):
            x = F.relu( self.Agentlayers1[i](state))
            x = F.relu( self.Agentlayers2[i](x))
            x_agent.append(F.softmax(self.outputLayer[i](x)))
        
        return x_agent
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "slowed down"? This code relies on `nn.ModuleList`, an alternative to a Python list. The indirection might hamper performance. It would be helpful if you could augment the question with the context in which ActorNetwork is called in. Finally, note that `nn.ModuleList` does not encode a neural network in itself - it's primarily used to store a sequence of layers.

Comment: Updated, but does it affect the speed?